# Window.Current.Content set with a frame but other pages do not navigate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am having an issue where the App.Xaml.cs has the following code:

```
        var gamePage = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (gamePage == null)
        {
            // Create a main GamePage
            gamePage = new Frame();

            if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                // TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }


            // Place the GamePage in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = gamePage;
            gamePage.Navigate(typeof(MainMenu));

        }

        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
```

Which is fairly standard for a an app initialization. This is also the same as how Microsoft outlines you should do it:

```
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx
```

however, when I call upon the frame again (in this case in the OnNavigateTo since for now I want to make sure I can switch around pages, this will be moved later) it does not do anything and sits on the same page. In other words as follows:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        var gamePage = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        gamePage.Navigate(typeof(GamePage));

    }
```

however, I cannot call this.Frame like Microsoft recommends me to which may or may not be an issue.

So, to recap, the issue is that I cannot navigate from page to page using the standard Frame object loaded into Window.Current.Content. I can verify that the app DOES go into the OnNavigateTo and the first page switch works just fine. However when I try to switch pages again, it does not work anymore.

Any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make `gamePad` a property (`public static Frame gamePage = new Frame();`) of the App.xaml.cs class and then, do something like:

```
 var gamePad = App.gamePage;
```

In other pages. This is the way its done in navigation with MVVM.